# Why can't get control panel name?

Tags: delphi, windows-shell, controlpanel

I use Shell to get control panel

Code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  psfDeskTop: IShellFolder;
  psfWork: IShellFolder; 
  pidworkDir: PITEMIDLIST;
  pidChild: PITEMIDLIST;
  pEnumList: IEnumIDList;
  celtFetched: ULONG;
  FileInfo: SHFILEINFOW;

begin

  Memo1.Clear;
  SHGetDesktopFolder(psfDeskTop);
  //control panel
  SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(0, CSIDL_CONTROLS, pidworkDir);  
  psfDeskTop.BindToObject(pidworkDir, nil, IID_IShellFolder, psfWork);
  psfWork.EnumObjects(0, SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS or SHCONTF_FOLDERS or SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN, pEnumList);
  while pEnumList.Next(1, pidChild, celtFetched) = 0 do
  begin

    SHGetFileInfo(LPCTSTR(pidChild), 0, FileInfo, SizeOf(FileInfo), SHGFI_PIDL
      or SHGFI_TYPENAME or SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME or SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES);

    Memo1.Lines.Add(FileInfo.szDisplayName + '   +');

  end;  
end;
```

it can't get `FileInfo.szDisplayName` , i just use  `'   +'`   to make Memo1 dispaly.
Why can't get control panel name ?

[image]

Comment: Well, step 1 is to add error checking to the code. Do that and update the question with the outcome.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan how add error checking to the code ?

Comment: Read the documentation for each API function and check return values for errors as described in the documentation. It's pointless to ask this question until you check for errors.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK , I will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on the shell. In fact I know practically nothing. But by reading the documentation I can glean the following:

1. `SHGetFileInfo` expects an absolute PIDL.
2. `IEnumIDList` enumerates relative PIDLs.

So you code is bound to fail because of that. Perhaps there are other errors too. I can't tell.

Anyway, I think the easy way to solve the problem is to use `IShellFolder.GetDisplayNameOf` to obtain the name you need:

```
uses
  ..., ShLwApi, ...
....
var
  StrRetName: TStrRet;
  Name: PChar;
....  
while pEnumList.Next(1, pidChild, celtFetched) = 0 do
begin
  OleCheck(psfWork.GetDisplayNameOf(pidChild, SHGDN_NORMAL, StrRetName));
  OleCheck(StrRetToStr(@StrRetName, nil, Name));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Name);
  CoTaskMemFree(Name);
  CoTaskMemFree(pidChild);
end;
```